# Return the max value based on two columns sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with the following schema:

```
User_id | Rating | Movie_id | Movie_Popularity
 1          2         34          100
 1          1         36          120
 1          2         39          110 
 2          3         34          105
```

What I would like is for each user find his max and his min rating and in case of a tie select the movie that has the highest popularity(suppose these are all distinct).

In this example the result would be:

```
User_id | Max_rating | Min_rating | Max_rating_movie_id | Min_rating_movie_id
     1          2         1                 39                  36
     2          3         3                 34                  34
```

I have tried sorting this table with both rating and movie popularity but I am able to extract only the max or the min value.

How could this be done using sql?

Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hi, you can use row_number() over (partition by .. order by ...asc) .

This a query sample:

```
   Select user_id, movie_id, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by rating desc) as max_rating, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by rating asc) as min_rating
```

Then you can use it as a sub query & select by where on max_rating & min_rating equals to 1.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions with aggregation:

```
select user_id, max(Movie_Popularity), min(Movie_Popularity),
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then movie_id end),
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then movie_id end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by Movie_Popularity asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by Movie_Popularity desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for subqueries.
You can do it with window functions `MIN()`, `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT User_id,
       MAX(Rating) OVER (PARTITION BY User_id) Max_rating,
       MIN(Rating) OVER (PARTITION BY User_id) Min_rating,
       FIRST_VALUE(Movie_id) OVER (PARTITION BY User_id ORDER BY Rating DESC, Movie_Popularity DESC) Max_rating_movie_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(Movie_id) OVER (PARTITION BY User_id ORDER BY Rating, Movie_Popularity DESC) Min_rating_movie_id
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e0b87d8983edb787d85aa9f50928927).
Results:

| User_id | Max_rating | Min_rating | Max_rating_movie_id | Min_rating_movie_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 39 | 36 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 34 | 34 |